# How can you create a custom filter for a Backbone collection?

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

I have three Backbone models/collections that I am using and I need to be able to create a custom filter similar to JavaScripts built in `.filter` method. I have a `Build` model which has a `Backbone.HasMany` relationship to my `Module` model. The third model is `Access` which has a specific build and a subset of modules from that build's module collection to allow access to a user.

I have a view that let's an admin edit an access. When the admin changes a build, I want the module list to automatically update itself accordingly using some type of filter, but I can't find one easily. Here is some pseudo-code for what I'm looking for...

```
var build = access.get('build');
var modules = access.get('modules'); //backbone collection of module models
function onBuildChange(new_build){
    modules = modules.filter(function(module)){
        //if the new build contains this module, keep it in the colleciton
        return new_build.contains(module);
    }
    //update the ui to only show the new modules
    this.render();
}
```

I've tried using just `.filter` on the collection and it didn't error out, but it just returns a JavaScript array. I know I could create a new collection off of that array, but I want to know if there is anything already built into Backbone that handles this. I know about `.where`, but I don't think this applies in this situation because it isn't simply checking if an attribute equals a value.

Thanks

Comment: I got it working by just using filter and `collection.reset()` on the filtered list afterwards. I wish there was a more elegant way, but this seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

All of the Collection methods are inherited from Underscore, which returns them as arrays, not as a new Collection. As you said, you could create a new Collection from the returned array, or you could use [Backbone.Collection.reset](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset) if you're trying to manipulate the current Collection.

Additionally, if you're looking to render a bunch of subviews within a view, using the array should work fine, as you'd just loop through the array and create a subview for each model (module?) returned and attach them to current view, without needing to manipulate the Collection itself.